# Find IP of my laptop on wifi network from Android

Tags: android, networking, air, wifi

I'm writing an Air app for Android that is going to interact with other apps on my laptop. They are going to be connected through WiFi. I've done everything to the point where I only need to know the IP address of my laptop on the WiFi network. How do I get it?

I would like to stay within Adobe Air without writing any native extensions if possible.

I can install any required software on the laptop to ease this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can "play" with your  laptop's IP, I asume you're going to use it on a "home" network, so, maybe you could just disable the use of DHCP on your computer and force the IP you want to use, in example,

> IP 192.168.1.25, gateway 192.168.1.1 mask 255.255.255.0

(assuming your network is the usual 192.168.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

The most common and efficient way to implement this is [Zero Configuration Networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking), Of cause, this requires extra native implementation, some available libraries are [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling) and [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/), both work with Android.